# Datatables - Column para Row

Tags: php, html

Necessito que uma coluna de uma tabela criada com o `DataTables` apareça em modo `row`, ou seja isto seria a tabela normal:

```
Id | InfoColuna | InfoColuna2 | InfoColuna3 |
---------------------------------------------
1# | InfoRow1   | InfoRow2    | InfoRow3    | 
--------------------------------------------- 
2# | InfoRow1.2 | InfoRow2.2  | InfoRow3.2  |
---------------------------------------------
```

Porém eu necessito que a coluna `InfoColuna3` deixe de ser uma coluna, e a info contida nela se apresente por baixo do `id` após carregar num botão.

Lembrando estar a usar HTML, JavaScript, PHP.

PS: Já usei as funções de `columns.visible`, porém isso só me esconde a coluna, ao mostrar, demonstra me todos os dados contidos nela.

Alguma ideia para resolver isto?

Comment: Este post deve dar sua resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server